# Cloud Formation template add ingress rule to existing security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

**Problem scope**

I have an application built using multiple cloud formation templates. They need to interact with each other but are too large/complicated to build in one template.

**Detail of scenario**

Imagine there were only two template (there are significantly more)

- Template A
- Template B

Template A creates a security group (security group A) with itself as the only ingress rule. It is applied to a series of hosts in this template that perform the same function.

Template B creates another security group (Security group B) and a number of hosts (in an elastic beanstalk).

**Question**

How can I add an ingress rule to *Security Group A* for traffic from *Security Group B* using *cloud formation*?

**What have I tried**

I have looked through the documentation, I want to create a security group Ingress rule and associate it with security group A but that doesn't seem to be viable as far as I can see - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html

**Other alternatives**

I could just use the CIDR range of the hosts that are in Security Group B as that is known before any of this is built (all in VPC's with separate subnets) however I feel there must be a better more secure way than accepting traffic from a cidr range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

You need to pass the security group identifier (for Security Group A) into the template for Template B as a parameter. From there, you can reference Security Group A in a `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress` resource.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters" : {
        "SecurityGroupA" : {
            "Description" : "Security group to add Ingress rule to",
            "Type"        : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id"
        }
    },
    "Resources" : {
        "LocalSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
        },
        "InboundRule": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
            "Properties":{
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": "80",
                "ToPort": "80",
                "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [ "LocalSecurityGroup", "GroupId" ]
                },
                "GroupId": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": [ "SecurityGroupA", "GroupId" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this example uses the security group ID, which is the case when your security groups are in a VPC. If they are in EC2-Classic, then you would use the `GroupName` instead.

Comment: Excellent exactly what I wanted. I just had not found a link to AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress. Thank you Matt.

Comment: Keep this bookmarked. It's a complete list of resource types: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html